# Install vFrabric tc server (as bundled with STS) into Linux EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have been developing a Spring MVC web app using Springsource Tool Suite (STS). STS comes with vFabric tc server developer edition I believe. When I deploy the .war file into my EC2 Linux AMI instance running tomcat6, there are incompatibilities between tomcat and vFabric.

For example, vFabric will accept objectName.getMethod() whereas it will return an error in tomcat6. I have to change it to objectName.method.

Here is my question. So, when making changes now, I don't use STS anymore and every change I have to package and redeploy which is time consuming. What is a good way around this?

I am thinking of installing the vFrabic tc server in my EC2 linux instance. Will that work? If I do that, theoretically, everything I develop in STS should be 100% compatible when deployed, correct?

Second question. How do I install vFrabic tc server in my EC2 instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion would be to develop inside of STS using a Tomcat server instead of tcServer.  However, then of course you loose some of the nice capabilities of tcServer.

If no one here can give you a complete answer, I would recommend the SpringSource forums (for STS):
http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?32-SpringSource-Tool-Suite

or here for tcServer:
http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?64-tc-Server-General